# Want to figure out BSOD, but there is no dump file or entry in system log file

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, event-log, minidumps

I recently got a Blue Screen of Death on my Windows 10 laptop.  I took a photo of the QR code, but it took me to a [generic and useless Microsoft web page](http://windows.com/stopcode).  My QR code app only keeps a history of the links, not the photos, so I do not remember what the stop code was.

I want to know why this BSOD occurred and if it might be a hardware or software problem.  Here is how I have the crash handling configured:

[image]

As you can see, the "Write an event to the system log" box is checked, and a dump file named C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP should be created.

However, when I looked at the System log in Event Viewer, I didn't see anything that seemed related to the BSOD around the time of the crash.  I read that there should be an entry from Source "BugCheck" for a BSOD, so I tried to filter the events with "Event sources"=BugCheck, but nothing was found.

There is also no file under C:\WINDOWS named MEMORY.DMP.

Why did Windows 10 not put an entry in the system log for the BSOD, and why didn't it create a dump file?  How else might I be able to determine what the bugcheck code was, and what caused it?

EDIT: Additional information:

- There is over 300 GB of free disk space on the C drive, so a lack of space is not the reason why the dump file wasn't created.

Comment: If there is no .dmp file then you cannot determine the reason for the crash.  The only reason it wouldn't create a .dmp file, is if it was unable to create the file itself, numerous reasons for why that woudln't be possible though.  "How else might I be able to determine what the bugcheck code was, and what caused it?" Give us the relevant information.

Comment: I edited the question to mention that there is plenty of free disk space on the C drive.  What other relevant information do you need?  But then you already said that without a .dmp file we cannot determine the reason.

Comment: I didn't mean there isn't free space, I mean, Windows wasn't able to create the file.  You indicated you had the QR code and the support article, and the bug check code

Comment: I edited the link from the QR code into the post.  I do not have the bugcheck code.

Comment: Without the stop code we can't help, what was happening, when the crash happened

Comment: OK, I was wondering if it was possible to find out what happened without any dump or log entry, so at least you cleared that up.  Thanks.  The computer was idle at the time of crash without any applications running, so it was definitely a strange occurrence.

Comment: have you disabled the pagefile? this is required to write dumps

Comment: @magicandre1981 My pagefile is 32 GB.

Comment: set the pagefile to "system managed" and look if you see a dmp after the next BSOD